# How should I connect my light fixture in this ceiling box?

Tags: electrical

[image: **enter image description here**]
Electrical box wire at 12 position is hot. That bundle has black white and ground. I Want to install light fixture with two wires...what is proper connections. I assume wire bundle at 3 o’clock is from switch red white black and ground...but just not sure how the connections should go
Thanks for any help

Comment: Aside from ground, which two were the old fixture attached to?

Comment: That red wire should be assumed to be hot or switched based on its color and should also be capped off.  Don't leave it exposed.

Comment: do a continuity check between "3 o clock" red-black as you operate the switch.  Obviously be absolutely certain the power is off first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wire nut two blacks together.  Push them back in the box.  Attach new fixture black to red. Connect all whites together.  Connect all grounds together.

[image]